# Bulk updating a slice of a Python list

Tags: python, list, slice, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have written a simple implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to perform one of the steps.

```
def eratosthenes(n):
    primes = [2]
    is_prime = [False] + ((n - 1)/2)*[True]
    for i in xrange(len(is_prime)):
        if is_prime[i]:
            p = 2*i + 1
            primes.append(p)
            is_prime[i*p + i::p] = [False]*len(is_prime[i*p + i::p])
    return primes
```

I am using Python's list slicing to update my list of booleans `is_prime`. Each element `is_prime[i]` corresponds to an odd number `2*i + 1`.

```
is_prime[i*p + i::p] = [False]*len(is_prime[i*p + i::p])
```

When I find a prime `p`, I can mark all elements corresponding to multiples of that prime `False`, and since all multiples smaller than `p**2` are also multiples of smaller primes, I can skip marking those. The index of `p**2` is `i*p + i`.

I'm worried about the cost of computing `[False]*len(is_prime[i*p + 1::p])` and I have tried to compare it to two other strategies that I couldn't get to work.

For some reason, the formula `(len(is_prime) - (i*p + i))/p` (if positive) is not always equal to `len(is_prime[i*p + i::p])`. Is it because I've calculated the length of the slice wrong, or is there something subtle about slicing that I haven't caught?

When I use the following lines in my function:

```
print len(is_prime[i*p + i::p]), ((len(is_prime) - (i*p + i))/p)
is_prime[i*p + i::p] = [False]*((len(is_prime) - (i*p + i))/p)
```

I get the following output (case `n = 50`):

```
>>> eratosthenes2(50)
7 7
3 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in eratosthenes2
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 2 to extended slice of size 3
```

I also tried replacing the bulk updating line with the following:

```
for j in xrange(i*p + i, len(is_prime), p):
    is_prime[j] = False
```

But this fails for large values of `n` because `xrange` doesn't take anything bigger than a long. I gave up on trying to wrestle `itertools.count` into what I needed.

Are there faster and more elegant ways to bulk-update the list slice? Is there anything I can do to fix the other strategies that I tried, so that I can compare them to the working one? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
is_prime[i*p + 1::p] = itertools.repeat(False, len(is_prime[i*p + 1::p]))
```

The slicing syntax will iterate over whatever you put on the right-hand side; it doesn't need to be a full-blown sequence.

So let's fix that formula.  I'll just [borrow the Python 3 formula](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/96d016f78726/Objects/rangeobject.c#l887) since we know that works:

```
1 + (hi - 1 - lo) / step
```

Since `step > 0`, `hi = stop` and `lo = start`, so we have:

```
1 + (len(is_prime) - 1 - (i*p + 1))//p
```

(`//` is integer division; this future-proofs our code for Python 3, but requires 2.7 to run).

Now, put it all together:

```
slice_len = 1 + (len(is_prime) - 1 - (i*p + 1))//p
is_prime[i*p + 1::p] = itertools.repeat(False, slice_len)
```

**Python 3 users**: Please do not use this formula directly.  Instead, just write `len(range(start, stop, step))`.  That gives the same result with similar performance (i.e. it's O(1)) and is much easier to read.

Comment: Nice try. Using timeit:  
  
>>> timeit.timeit('eratosthenes0(10000000)', setup="from __main__ import eratosthenes0, count", number=1)  
3.1473147869110107  
  
>>> timeit.timeit('eratosthenes1(10000000)', setup="from __main__ import eratosthenes1; from itertools import repeat, count", number=1)  
4.1984710693359375

Comment: @castle-bravo: The formula you posted for the length looks right to me.  Please provide a *specific* example where it is wrong.

Comment: using the formula that I posted:  >>> eratosthenes2(50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in eratosthenes2
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 2 to extended slice of size 3

Comment: @castle-bravo: OK, I fixed it.

Comment: So far my original version is still the fastest. For primes <= 10000000, I have ~3.15s for the original, ~4.2s for itertools.repeat with len(slice), ~3.3s for [False]*formula, and ~4.4s with itertools.repeat with formula.

Comment: You get the checkmark on account of correcting my formula.

Comment: Try cProfile.  It may be that your slowness is caused by something else.